# Fail to autowire dependency in test

Tags: spring, autowired, spring-test

I'd like to write a Spring integration test to make sure that `@Autowired` correctly puts together my classes, but fail.

The test class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = {ClassUnderTest.class, SomRepository.class, SomeEntity.class})
public class ClassUnderTestIT{

    @Autowired private InterfaceUnderTest cut;

    @Test public void autowires() {
        assertThat(cut).isNotNull();
    }

}
```

Should test that this `@Service` autowires

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ClassUnderTest implements InterfaceUnderTest {

    private final SomeRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public DefaultWatchlistDataModifier(SomeRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

}
```

Paying special attention to the wired dependency

```
@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Scope(value = BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public interface SomeRepository extends JpaRepository<SomeEntity, String> {
}
```

However, all I ever get is the exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
No qualifying bean of type 'com.[...].InterfaceUnderTest' available:
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
Dependency annotations: 
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Meanwhile, I have experimented with all kinds of additional annotations, such as `@ComponentScan`, `@EnableJpaRepositories` ... whatever I could dig up in the endless number of StackOverflow questions on the topic - all in vain.

Comment: `@DataJpaTest` only bootstraps JPA related classes. Your class you want to test isn't a JPA class and hence isn't detected. You need an `@SpringBootTest` in this case. Also `@EntityScan` here doesn't make any sense either.

Comment: Blimey, you're perfectly right, of course! Mind making this an answer I can vote up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`@DataJpaTest`] will only bootstrap the JPA part of your Spring Boot application. As the unit of your test isn't part of that subset it will not be available in the application context.

Either construct it yourself and inject the dependencies or use a full blown `@SpringBootTest` instead.

Comment: Full-blown Spring test it is then. Injecting mocks is exactly what I don't want to do here. On the test class, removed `@DataJpaTest` and `@EntityScan` and added `@SpringBootTest` instead. That fixed it. Thanks!